# Scroll bars in IE 9 + Silverlight 4

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight-4.0, internet-explorer-9

If I create a new silverlight application using all of the defaults in visual studio and run the application I see the mess displayed in the image. This does not happen in Chrome. I believe its only in IE9 and not IE8.

Can others reproduce, or explain?

[image: scrollbar bug]

Answer (score 0):

Try to toggle the compatibility view.